# Webpack prevent emit css for some files with css modules

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to configure webpack in such a way, that for a certain *.css* files it does not emit css(does not add anything to styles.css), but emits locals(className to style mapping in the imported object in js). In *css-loader* `modules` option is always enabled (aka [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)). For example:

In some *.js* file:

```
import cssNoEmit from './styles.noemit.scss'
import cssEmit from './styles.scss'
```

the contents of *styles.noemit.scss*:

```
.testNoEmit {
  background: orange;
}
```

the contents of *styles.scss*:

```
.testEmit {
  background: blue;
}
```

What i want to achieve is that the final generated *.css* contains `.testEmit` class only. Also, both `cssNoEmit` and `cssEmit` contain mappings to a relevant classes in the generated *.css*

It may by possible to solve this with `extract-text-plugin`, but i'm not looking for that solution, since this plugin is deprecated.

Here is what i have tried:

**All the attempts have reproductible examples [here](https://github.com/danierlr/SO_NoCssEmit)**

**EDIT**: attempts 1 (thanks to @felixmosh) and 5 managed to work.

**Attempt 1 (working)**. *css-loader* has an option `onlyLocals`. The description in the *css-loader* [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#onlylocals) is very vague, but as i understand it is supposed to do the exactly the same thing i am trying to achieve.

```
  {
    test: /\.noemit\.scss$/,
    use: [
      //MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // after disabling this, it started to work
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            mode: 'local',
            exportGlobals: true,
            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            hashPrefix: '_',
          },
          importLoaders: 2,
          onlyLocals: true, // setting this to true causes transpilation to crash
        },
      },
      
      ...

    ],
  },
```

**Attempt 5 (working, not perfectly)**. Trying to use webpack built-in feature, SplitChunksPlugin. I tried to create a config for this use case based on [this](https://github.com/thecrypticace/webpack-css-chunks-test/blob/master/webpack.config.js), [SplitChinksPlugin docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/), [this](https://www.excitoninteractive.com/articles/read/66/webpack4/step-by-step-split-chunks-plugin), [this](https://openbase.io/js/mini-css-extract-plugin).

```
  ...

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        groupUnusedStyles: {
          name: "unusedStyles",
          chunks: "all",

          test: /\.noemit\.scss$/,

          enforce: true
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

This approach redirects unwanted css into *unusedStyles.css*

It works, with one small, but frustrating drawback. Apart from unusedStyles.css it generates unusedStyles.js and this has to be included in html, otherwise the app won't run.

To be more specific, both chunks have to be inside html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/unusedStyles.bundle.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how to make it work without needing to add another bundle?

**Attempt 2 (not working)**. Don't use `onlyLocals` setting and ommit a loader that is responsible for the "css output"(such as `style-loader` or `mini-extract-css-plugin`). In this case the contents of imported css are very strange

[image: strange contents of the imported object in javascript]

**Attempt 3 (not working)** `null-loader` does not work either, as it imports just an empty object

**Attempt 4 (not working)**. [There](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/90) is another idea:

```
class ServerMiniCssExtractPlugin extends MiniCssExtractPlugin {
  getCssChunkObject(mainChunk) {
    return {};
  }
}

... // use ServerMiniCssExtractPlugin the same way as MiniCssExtractPlugin
```

This does not work, because final *.css* has all the styles, as if normal MiniCssExtractPlugin was used

Also, [there](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/45) is a related thread on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is the correct one, just remove `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` from the `noemit.scss` loader list.

I've tried it locally, it works, the out css contains only the none "noemit" files but there is css-modules object mapping for both.

The removed loader (MiniCssExtractPlugin) is the one that responsible to include the scss in the final css file.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you explain please, why it works? By the way, i managed to make 5th attempt work too.

Comment: I've added an explanation in the answer